# HIVE_BAD_DATA: Wrong type using parquets on AWS Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I've created a Glue Crawler to read files from S3 and create a table for each S3 path. The table health_users were created using a wrong type for a specific column: the column two_factor_auth_enabled were created as int instead of string.

Manually, I went to Glue Catalog and updated the schema of table health_users.

After that, I tried to run the query again on Athena and it still throwing the same error:

> Your query has the following error(s):
>
> HIVE_BAD_DATA: Field two_factor_auth_enabled's type BOOLEAN in parquet is incompatible with type int defined in table schema
>   This query ran against the "test_parquets" database, unless qualified by the query. Please post the error message on our forum or contact customer support with Query Id: c3a86b98-70a2-4c70-97d8-8bc377c455b8.

I've checked the table structure on Athena and the column two_factor_auth_enabled is a string (the file attached shows table definition):

[image]

What's wrong with my solution? How can I fix this error?

Comment: Why do you need that field as string? Have you tried to change it from int to boolean? Anyway, parquet inherently has data type info about its’ fields, whereas you have only changed hive definition. I would’ve created an athena view on top of the original table where I would use `CAST ...` for that column.

Comment: Can you re-run the Glue crawler after changing the column type to boolean and setting "Update all new and existing partitions with metadata from the table" in Glue crawler settings?

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy I don't want that column as boolean. I want the column as String.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution for this problem?